# Remove an item from an associative array php

Tags: php, arrays

How can I remove from this array the current selected language:

```
$lang = 'en-US';
$languages = array('LANG001' => 'en-US', 'LANG002' => 'es-ES', 'LANG003' => 'fr-CA');
```

I try with `unset($languages[$lang])` without success.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
unset($languages[array_search($lang,$languages,true)]);
```

Comment: Your solution works but why `unset($languages[$lang])` did not make the job ?

Comment: @user3741025 Because `$lang` is the value, not the index, of the element you want to remove.

Comment: because unset(array[key]) is looking for the key name, and $lang contains the key value

Answer (score 1):

1) The index in an array expression must be the key, not the value. If you want to delete an element by the value, you have to find its key first.

```
$key = array_search($lang, $languages);
if ($key) {
    unset($languages[$key]);
}
```

However, this will only remove the first occurrence of the value in the array. If the value can appear multiple times and you want to remove all of them, you can do:

```
$languages = array_diff($languages, array($lang));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to echo specific values in a loop?

You'd use a loop to echo values depending on a pattern or simply every value.

To access variables inside of a loop, you'd do it the same way as everywhere else in a script,
check if the variable exists then echo that specific var.

Simply use

```
(isset($languages['LANG001']) ? echo $languages['LANG001'] : null);

(isset($languages['LANG002']) ? echo $languages['LANG002'] : null);
```